# Parse HTML string from a file and remove element using xpath and write it to same file in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, lxml

For my project, I have to remove selective content from a html file using python xpath. 
The selective element can be removed using .remove() method, however the content in file looks same.

How do I write the modified content to that file again?

Though If i try to write the same tree object to file using open().write(etree.tostring(tree_obj)), will the content differs for unicode pages? Is there anyother way to keep the modified file?

Why the header tags in below output has different value after printing the tree object?

Please suggest.

Below is my code sample.
Example: I need to remove all div tags inside the html page.

HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>test</head>
<body>
<p>welcome to the world</p>
<div id="one">
    <p>one</p>
    <div id="one1">one1</div>
    <ul>
        <li>ones</li>
        <li>twos</li>
        <li>threes</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="hell">
    <p>heaven</p>
    <div id="one1">one1</div>
    <ul>
        <li>ones</li>
        <li>twos</li>
        <li>threes</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter something.." />
<input type="button" value="click" />
</body>
</html>
```

Python file:

```
# _*_ coding:utf-8 _*_

import os
import sys
import traceback
import datetime
from lxml import etree, html
import shutil

def process():
    fd=open("D:\\hello.html")
    tree = html.fromstring(fd.read())
    remove_tag = '//div'
    for element in tree.xpath(remove_tag):
        element.getparent().remove(element)
    print etree.tostring(tree)

process()
```

OUTPUT:

```
<html>
<head/><body><p>test
</p>
<p>welcome to the world</p>
<input type="text" placeholder="enter something.."/>
<input type="button" value="click"/>


</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on python but i have played with parsing html based websites using Java with help of library jsoup.

Python also has similar one like [this](http://watchitlater.com/blog/2010/09/jsoup-beautifulsoup-for-java/). Beautiful soup. You can play with this thing to get desired output.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using python's standard library re?

```
import re</br>
re.sub('<.*?>','', '<nb>foobar<aon><mn>')
re.sub('</.*?>','', '</nb>foobar<aon><mn>')
```

The above two operations could be used in combination to remove all the html tags. It can be easily modified to remove the div tags too.

Comment: @roshan - we can remove the tags using .remove() easily. The problem here is the input file content is not changing unless we write the content again.

Comment: Try to open the file in r+ mode. Something like fd=open("D:\\hello.html","r+")